# How can i upload an image to firebase with the same name?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have this code to upload a file to firebase, it working when i upload for example

a.jpg, b.jpg a.jpg c.jpg a.jpg

but does not working when i try to upload again for example:

at the firebase is saved these images a.jpg, b.jpg a.jpg c.jpg a.jpg now i am trying to addicion another a.jpg, the older pictures with this name a.jpg its not allowed to show

```
const addPicture = (
  path1,
  path2,
  picture,
) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const reStorage = fbStorage.ref(`${path1}/${path2}`)
      reStorage
        .put(picture)
        .then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.ref
              .getDownloadURL()
              .then(url => {
                resolve(url)
              })
              
          }
```

each time the token is going to change
first was `&token=32332b7c-f0d0-426b-b651-0215361b519f`
later was `&token=3278687a-f5d0-426b-b651-0432432444qr`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen can you help me please

Answer (score 0):

The token that is used for the downloadURL that Firebase provides is stored in the item's metadata.

I haven't tried this with the web client, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
const ref = fbStorage.ref(....)
ref.getMetadata().then(metadata) => {

  return ref.put(picture).then(snapshot => {

    return snapshot.ref.updateMetadata(metadata)
      .then(() => snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL())

  })

})
```